# Algebra with differential $k$-forms (in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to follow some notes to understand differential forms within the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but am tripped up by the formalities involved with the introduction of a differential $k$-form. It is introduced as follows:

For an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ be the vector space of all expressions of the form $\sum_I f_I(x)dx_I$, where $f_I: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, $I = (i_1, \dots, i_k)$, and $dx_I = dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_k}$.

Conceptually, it is not too hard to understand the basic algebraic operations involving this space $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$. There is addition, multiplication by functions, and wedge product, where wedge product is a map $\wedge : \mathcal{A}^k(U) \times \mathcal{A}^l(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^{k+l}(U)$. However, the problem is regarding the formal statement of calling $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ a $\textbf{vector}$ space. A vector space is over a field, but unless I am missing something, smooth functions (acting as the coefficients here) do not form a field, meaning $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ is not a vector space.

Is this a problem? Practically speaking, I am basically comfortable with performing the previously mentioned algebraic operations - it is just that I don't formally consider this space to be a vector space. Will there be any consequences down the road for not appreciating exactly what algebraic structure $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ forms?
Lastly, just to be complete, what type of space is $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ actually? My guess was a 'module over a ring' (i.e. same as a vector space, but without the ability to divide coefficients), but I believe this would not incorporate the ability to multiply differential $k$-forms via wedge product. Would this make $\bigcup_{k \geq 0} \mathcal{A}^k(U)$ a '(graded) algebra'? If so, what do we call $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ alone?

Sorry for the wordy question, but thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: ${\cal A}^k(U)$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb R$

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate? This does not make sense to me. It seems to me that the vectors would need to be of the form $\sum_Ic_Idx_I$, with $c_I \in \mathbb{R}$. Instead, the 'vectors' are of the form $\sum_If_I(x)dx_I$, where $f_I$ is a smooth function. I realize that these $f_I$ will evaluate to a real number at a particular point, but no such point has been specified. In fact, I thought the purpose was to treat the functions $f_I$ in their entirety, such that they can be differentiated.

Comment: @t42d It's fine that the coefficients are functions. As long as you can add and scalar multiply by $\mathbb{R}$, you have a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. It is an infinite-dimensional vector space in this case, of course.

Comment: if $C^{\infty}(U)$ is the ring of smooth functions over $U$ then ${\cal A}^k(U)$ is a $C^{\infty}(U)$-module, and $\bigcup_k{\cal A}^k(U)$ a $C^{\infty}(U)$-graded algebra.

Comment: @Kajelad I am unsure about this. Are you maybe referring to the free vector space over $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$? I was under the assumption that we wanted to view this space as a finite-dimensional space, specifically $\binom{n}{k}$-dimensional, with basis $\{dx_I : I \subseteq [n], |I| = k\}$. For instance, we should have that $f_I(x)dx_I + g_I(x)dx_I = (f_I + g_I)(x)dx_I$, but I don't think such an equality would hold in the free vector space.

Comment: @janmarqz Thanks for clarifying. But would this create any problems in terms of defining the dimension of $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$? I believe we want $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ to be a $\binom{n}{k}$ dimensional space, with 'basis' $\{dx_I : I \subseteq [n], |I| = k\}$. But I am not sure if dimension and basis are defined in the context of a $C^\infty (U)$-module.

Comment: @t42d I'm not talking about the free vector space. The addition is$$\sum_If_Idx_I+\sum_Ig_Idx_I=\sum_I(f_I+g_I)dx_I$$and the scalar multiplication by $\mathbb{R}$ is defined simply by$$c\left(\sum_If_Idx_I\right)=\sum_I(cf_I)dx_I$$where $c\in\mathbb{R}$. The space of differential forms above *a single point* is a $\binom{n}{k}$ dimensional vector space, but the space of differential forms over $U$ (or any space of positive dimension) is infinite-dimensional (as is, for instance, the space of smooth functions $C^\infty U$). It is *also* a $C^\infty(U)$-mudule, of course.

Comment: @t42d It seems that the spoint of confusion is that you are thinking of the expressions $\sum_If_Idx_I$ as an expansion into components in a basis (in the context of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces). It is *not*; the forms $dx_I$ form a *frame*, not a *basis*, and you will in fact have a very hard time writing down a basis for $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ even if you wanted to. You shouldn't think of yourself as working in a basis at all, and just think of working in an abstract $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Comment: @Kajelad I see, yes this is precisely why I have been confused. Thank you for clarifying this point. For me, it is tempting to view the $dx_I$'s as a basis. Would it be correct to say that $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ is a $C^\infty(U)$ -module which is spanned by the $dx_I$s? Also, when you say that the space of differential forms above a single point, say $p \in U$, form a $\binom{n}{k}$-dim. vector space, is this because we are identifying each $f_I$ with its image $f_I(p) \in \mathbb{R}$? Since in particular the constant functions are smooth, we can realize all of $\mathbb{R}$ this way.

Comment: @t42d Yes, $dx_I$ *are* a basis in the $C^\infty(U)$-module sense, just not in the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space sense. I'm being somewhat imprecise when I talk about differential forms "above a single point", but what I mean is more or less what you say. In the modern language, we would say that $\mathcal{A}^k(U)$ is the space of smooth sections of a rank $\binom{n}{k}$ [vector bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) (specifically the exterior power of the cotangent bundle $\Lambda^k(T^*U)$).

Comment: @Kajelad I think the modern language is still beyond me, but hopefully it will make sense in the (near?) future. In any case, thank you for clarifying my misconception with your thorough responses!